# Style <rich:tooltip> to look like HTML title

Tags: css, jsf, tooltip, richfaces

I got a JSF page which has a `<rich:tooltip>` as well as an arbitrary component with a `title` attribute.
Those two do neither look, nor act in the same way.

HTML `title` attribute has rounded corners, a black border, a smaller font and does not show directly on mouseover.

Do you have any idea, how I can achieve a more similar behaviour on both tooltips? I thought of CSS styling via the `styleClass` option of `<rich:tooltip>`.

Answer (score 0):

The appearance of @title depends on the browser and OS, you cannot style it with CSS. You can try making the tooltip look the same but on a different computer they might be different anyway.